# How do I say "typeface" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, typography

How do I say "typeface" (that is "font family") in Latin?
The Wikipedia page is translated under the title "Typus" but there is a banner saying "Latinitas huius rei maxime dubia est. Corrige si potes."

I assume such a word is attested in Latin since many font designs date back to the 16th century.

Comment: What about "litterarum formae"?